# NSURLSession upload task doesn't call completionHandler

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsurlsession

I am using **NSURLSession** upload task to send **HTTP POST** request with **JSON** data with the following code snippet.

```
NSData* requestData = [json_string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURL *remote_url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://<some ip>:<port>"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request =
[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:remote_url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:requestData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"response received...");
}];

NSLog(@"log before resume");
[uploadTask resume];
NSLog(@"log after resume");
```

I do receive data at server end and server sends **HTTP 200 response**. However,

```
NSLog(@"log after resume");
NSLog(@"response received...");
```

are never called. Why does `resume` block and never calls `completionHandler`?

Comment: Is it possible that you're doing something wrong at the server end?

Comment: I don't have the problem with the blocking after [uploadTask resume] BUT since I updated my simulator to iOS 10, the execution never reaches the completion block for me too. Before that with iOS 9, it was always getting there on success or on error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an obvious problem with your code. Perhaps your `session.delegateQueue` is blocked?

Another tack: you could skip the completion handler block, and try setting the `NSURLSession.delegate` property, and use the `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` callback, just to see if you can get it to work. E.g.,

```
@interface DelegateClass <NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>
@end

@implementation DelegateClass

(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, task.response);
}

@end

// ...

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
session.delegate = [[DelegateClass alloc] init];
// ...

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:requestData];
[uploadTask resume];
```

Free naming advice: having been down this road myself, I believe you'll save yourself unnecessary angst by committing to idiomatic CamelCase names (vs. mixing with snake_cased `json_string` and `remote_url`) .

Comment: But none of that explains why _his_ code doesn't work. And how can the delegate queue be blocked? It's the shared session.

Comment: Point 1: if delegate callbacks worked, but the completion handler didn't, it would be a pretty good clue. Bonus: working code. Point 2: It may be a long shot, but is it *impossible* that the shared session's `delegateQueue` is blocked?